# How to handle parameters which being injected from 'VM Options" in java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, jvm

I am using a code which connect to amazon S3 and I want to supply secret and access key outside the code (because I don't want to save it when I save it in Git).

I am trying to use VM Options in order to supply those parameters and to be able to read them from my code. I am using java.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply properties to VM while invoking java command specifyng the `-D` switch.

```
java -cp [myClassPath] -D[mypropName]=[myvalue] [myMainClass]
```

Then in Your java application you can access your property as follow:

```
public String retreiveMyProperty() {
   return  System.getProperty("[mypropName]");
}
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

This chunk of code which reads from VM Options:

```
 private List<String> getAmazonParams() {
        List<String> s3CredentialsList = new ArrayList<>();
        s3CredentialsList.add(System.getProperty("access_key"));
        s3CredentialsList.add(System.getProperty("secret_key"));
        return s3CredentialsList;

    }
```

and this is how I supply it from VM Options:

```
-ea -Daccess_key=<access_key> -Dsecret_key=<secret_key>
```